# Looping over Monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am really new to Haskell, so this might be a stupid question. I have a function

```
foo :: Int -> IO ()
```

whose result will print some useful information. Now I want to do this:

```
do
    foo 0
    foo 1
    foo 0
    foo 2
    foo 3
```

How can I write this as a loop? My problem is to 'concatenate' the Monads, which is done automatically by the do statement...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Did you mean the series `[0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3]` ?

Comment: Just so you know, you are using the terminology incorrectly.  `IO` is a monad, `IO ()` (and `IO Int`, `IO a`, etc.) is a type, and `foo 0` is a value of type `IO ()` (common words for something like `foo 0` are "action", "monadic action", or "monadic computation").  So you are trying to concatenate (or, more commonly "sequence") the actions, not the monads -- there's only one monad here and it is `IO`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mapM_ foo [0,1,0,2,3]` will do the trick.

What's perhaps more important is "how does one figure that out?" [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is a wonderful tool. You want to apply a function with signature `Int -> IO ()` to a bunch of `Int`s to get a new IO action. The thing you're looking for will thus have signature `(Int -> IO ()) -> [Int] -> IO ()`, so we go and [ask Hoogle for functions with that signature](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28Int%20-%3E%20IO%20%28%29%29%20-%3E%20%5BInt%5D%20-%3E%20IO%20%28%29). The second result is [`mapM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mapM_), whose signature is

```
Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()
```

Right, so `mapM_` in fact works with *any* monad (not just `IO`) and *any* type (not just `Int`). When you think about it, that's not surprising at all.

Comment: Thank you for the Hoogle-hint! That will be very very helpful :)

Answer (score 12):

You want the `mapM_` combinator, which maps a function returning a monadic value over a list, and uses the bind operator to sequence the results:

```
>> let foo n = putStrLn (show n ++ "!")
>> mapM_ foo [0,1,0,2,3]
0!
1!
0!
2!
3!
```

Sometimes people like to use the flipped version

```
for :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
for = flip mapM_
```

which looks more like imperative code:

```
>> for [1..5] $ \n ->
     putStrLn ("Number: " ++ show n)
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Number: 4
Number: 5
```

Note that a combinator called `forM_` is defined in `Control.Monad` and does exactly the same thing as the combinator I've called `for`.

Comment: Huh? What was that edit about? `forM_` is the correct name, as [used by the standard libraries](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Foldable.html#v:forM-95-).

Comment: Since I was providing the definition, I felt like I could call it whatever I wanted. Calling it `for` makes the analogy with imperative languages clearer. And there's [precedent](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=for). I don't think that answers on Stack Overflow (which are primarily pedagogical) should necessarily be bound by the conventions in the standard library (which need to weigh pedagogy and convenience against the need to fit well into the menagerie of other, similarly named, functions).